# Who plans to go to TUG 2018 in Rio de Janeiro?

Tags: discussion

[image: The lion!]

Hello ladies and gentlemen, boys and girls, ducks and mallards, marmots and capybaras, Darth Vaders and parrot owners, children of all ages!

[image: Lion]

The [39th Annual Meeting of the TeX Users Group (TUG 2018)](http://tug.org/tug2018) will be held in the awesome city of Rio de Janeiro, from July 20 to 22, as an official satellite conference of International Congress of Mathematicians 2018 (ICM 2018). It will be the very first TUG meeting in South America!

So, I'd like to ask our beloved community:

- Who would like to go there?
- Does anybody plan to make a presentation?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: fixed. `:)`

Comment: I'd come if it were in Jerusalem...

Comment: Brazil has recently called up the military to control violence in Rio de Janeiro. For all those that will be travelling, please take care.

Answer (score 18):

## I will go! Woooooooooooo!

I plan at least one presentation, hopefully about `arara`4.0, which I also plan the official release around that time, as part of the celebrations. `:)`

Also, I will try bringing my TeX lion puppet to the conference:

[image: Quack]

Of course, I plan a lot of silly activities. Beware, for I am very friendly: if you pass by, I will say hello and start talking nonstop because we ducks are very talkative! `:)` I am also trying to improve my German and Italian as a means to annoy people in other languages!

In case you haven't seen it, here's a link to my [invitational video](https://vimeo.com/243630927).

See you in Rio de Janeiro! Quack!

<sub>It's also worth mentioning that, for reasons unbeknownst to me, the TUG blokes thought I should be part of the local committee, so that makes me some sort of official spokesduck of the event. So feel free to ask stuff! I will do my best and try to answer!</sub>

Comment: Although not attending I am scared about the silly activities ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: There will be a naughty moose. `:)`

Comment: Alright, but don't mention the war ;-)

Answer (score 12):

I plan to come to Rio and I look forward to a great event!

I would be happy if I could contribute a bit. Possible presentations:

- **TeX in Industry:** more stuff about using TeX in a network engineer's life
- **TeX Websites:** could be a survey of various websites (supported by TUG & DANTE) and specifically presenting a new webservice for TeX users (details later)
- An announcement of some useful thing (in progress, details later)
- *optional, if somebody is interested,* **Graphics in TeX and LaTeX:** showing today's graphics capabilities with a lot of pictures and sample code lines

Comment: YAAAAAAAAAAAAAY

Comment: On a more serious note, and on behalf of the local committee, I want to thank you for coming to Rio de Janeiro and honour us with your presence! Please let me know if can be of assistance. Also, I might plan something extra for my friends...

Answer (score 11):

I'm currently planning to go (time/funds allowing). Likely topics for talks are

- `l3build` (it is written in Lua ...)
- `siunitx` v3 (fingers-crossed)
- Unicode 'stuff'
- Perhaps `beamer` ...

Comment: YAAAAAAAAAAAAAY

Comment: Joseph, on behalf of the local committee, I want to personally thank you for considering this overseas trip! It would be awesome to have you with us. Also, on a light note, UK-TUG already has two confirmed members. `:)`

Answer (score 11):

"My husband and I" are planning to come. I don't know yet if I will give a talk -- I would need a good idea first ;-)

But I already made an advertisement (an animated version with suitable background music can be found in the  tikzducks christmas extravaganza video, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405060/2388):

[image]

Some are excited already:

[image][image]

Comment: Ulrike, it will be great to have you and your husband with us! On behalf of the local committee, thank you for joining us in this special occasion! About the talk, I might have a suggestion, stay tuned... `:)`

Comment: I have also a suggestions for a talk: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRbG6.png

Comment: @samcarter I think we will manage it somehow ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to hear! I see you are already well prepared for the trip!

Answer (score 10):

**Me. I hope to give a talk or a package in preparation.**

Comment: Tom, that's awesome news, I am so happy to hear you are coming! On behalf of the local committee, thank you very much! Yay!

Answer (score 8):

I'm Arthur, an adventurous `tikzduck`. I'd like to hitchhike to Rio. Is there anyone who could give me a lift?

Don't worry I have my towel and guide with me.

Hope to see you all soon!

[image]

---

@samcarter speaking: unfortunately I cannot come to Rio myself, but I'd love to sent a talk about the `tikzduck`. If anybody would be interested to show a few slides, please ping me!

Comment: We will miss you! Regarding a potential talk, I have someone in mind. `:)` In any case, I'd love to be the fallback speaker! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

I'm seriously looking into going to Rio. Funds are a bit tight at the moment, though. If I go -- and if the organizers are amenable, of course -- I could give a presentation on the [selnolig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package.

Comment: Yay, it's great to hear you are considering the possibility of coming, Mico! It will be a great conference, and I will do my best to ensure my friends will have a good time!

Comment: Mico, any updates on TUG 2018? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda - Good news (I think!): I can make it!! I am very much looking forward to participating. (I'm set to arrive the evening of Thu, July 19 and to depart late on Monday, July 23.)  Please let me know if there's still space in the conference program for a presentation on the `selnolig` package. If that's considered to be too obscure or technical (after all, it relies heavily on LuaTeX's callback features), do let me know, and I'll think of something else to give a presentation on.

Comment: Fantastic! I will poke you in a minute!

Answer (score 7):

I am 90%–95% sure I can make it!

If I present it will be hurried and last minute. And I promise not to run ridiculously overtime like in Portland :(

Comment: Yay, I like those odds! `:)` On behalf of the local committee, thanks for considering the conference, Will! Regarding the presentation, you will have about 20 hours of flight to prepare it, so time won't be a problem. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda I thouht ... 20 hours to _present_ it :-)

Answer (score 6):

Really, really nice to know it will be in Brazil. Unfortunately I don't know if I can go but, if anyone need help with Brazilian stuff (tips, Portuguese language, etc), let me know. :-)

Comment: The committee will soon publish the fees, so feel free to poke me if I can be of assistance! `:)`

Answer (score 6):

How sad it is, but from Japan it is financially hardly feasible for me, and above that I would have a hard time explaining the trip to my company.  So how much I would love to see Rio, I see no chance to make it over :-(
I could give quite a lot of talks, though :-(((

Everyone enjoy the time and the conference, it will surely be great!

Comment: We will miss you, Norbert! I completely understand, it's indeed a long and expensive journey overseas. We will do our best to make everybody feel welcome, and hopefully I will report everything! `:)`

Comment: Thanks Paulo, trust me, not coming to Rio was one of the hardest decisions in recent times. But paying for three (my daughter will be just over 2, so no free flight) all the way to Rio is unfortunately impossible :-(

Answer (score 5):

I would have liked, but I cannot go. A pity when there is so much to see in Brazil (and don't be evil minded, I am thinking now in nice waterfalls, wild sparrows ... and well, in the conference also, of course). I hope a nice time in Rio to all participants!

Comment: It would be awesome to have you with us! I know I cannot reveal some details, but the conference rooms might have some wild animal friends during the talks. Some of them are *very* noisy! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm from Argentina and I'd love to go, but unfortunately I'm studying at university (although learning to use TeX better every day).

From my place as an apprentice and reader of this site I wish the speakers the best for this 39th Annual Meeting of the TeX User Group!! And for more adventurous `tikzducks`!

P.S.: Will I be able to see the talks offered on the Internet?

Comment: ¡Hola amigo! I wish you all the best in your endeavours in the university, it's a fantastic time in life! On behalf of the local committee, we will do our best to make this meeting the best so far! It's very important for us Latin Americans, and it's a nice opportunity to make the New World known for our TeX dedication! `:)` I will double-check about live transmission and report back as soon as possible. At least, videos will certainly be available after the meeting. For now, hasta pronto!

Comment: Oi @PauloCereda! Obrigado for your words! I think that in recent years Latin Americans (and why not especially Argentines) feel more involved in the technologies of the future (Word went out of style!), learning from those who know best and who always have an answer to everything. *This site is one of them*. Thank you for making this possible day by day Paulo! And to all the people who make this possible too, a well deserved applause! I will be attentive to the talks ao vivo `:)`.

Saudações

Comment: Ooooh, another `tikzducks` fan!

Comment: Oh yeah, I love them!

Comment: @manooooh For the tikzduck fan from Argentina: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27OYn.png

Comment: Yeeeeey! It's the best `tikzduck` of all @samcarter, thank you very much! Look at my profile picture `:)`.

Quack quack!

Comment: @manooooh Yeah!

Comment: Nice profile picture! `:)`